# My ElasticSearch Indexes have been mysteriously deleted, how to debug?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I just checked my ElasticSearch server and the indexes are gone, there is no index remaining. I don't see any information in the /var/logs/elasticsearch and not sure what to look for.

1) How do I debug what went wrong and how it got deleted?
2) My elasticsearch is accessible via a public IP on the 9200 port, I haven't done anything to secure it, can it be that? Also, how do I secure it especially when I need to use it myself to call from my own set of servers.

Mostly trying to figure what went wrong and how to prevent it from happening again.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is caused by deleting by the HTTP services from Internet.

**Question 1:**

Maybe you can update your log level to trace this, see [Logging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/logging.html)

**Question 2:**

1. Build an internal domain for elasticsearch, this can't access from public domain.
2. Use [X-Pack](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/x-pack) with authorization for elasticsearch cluster.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have been target in newest ransom hack spree. Your ES cluster was probably not secured.

Search for message in logs

```
SEND 0.2 BTC TO THIS WALLET: 1DAsGY4Kt1a4LCTPMH5vm5PqX32eZmot4r IF YOU WANT RECOVER YOUR DATABASE! SEND TO THIS EMAIL YOUR SERVER IP AFTER SENDING THE BITCOINS p1l4t0s@sigaint.org
```

See

> https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ransom-attack-on-elasticsearch-cluster/71310
>
> http://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/01/13/elasticsearch_mongodb/